# hide <th> and <td> tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
<table class="display" id="jquerytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>BillingAddress</th>
      <th>DeliveryAddress</th>
      <th>Eng 1</th>
      <th>Eng 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= Html.Encode(item.Name) %></td>
      <td><%= Html.Encode(item.BillingAddress) %></td>
      <td><%= Html.Encode(item.DeliveryAddress) %></td>
      <td><%= Html.Encode(item.Engineer1Id) %></td>
      <td><%= Html.Encode(item.Engineer2Id) %></td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I hide th Eng 1 and Eng 2? I try wit visible = "false" but not successful.

Comment: If you give the item a class or ID then in jQuery (which I assume you are using from the jquerytable reference) you can hide it with $("#myId").hide() or $(".myClass").hide()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MattMitchell is mostly right; you really want to use:

```
<th style="visibility: hidden;">
```

The difference between `display: none;` and `visibility: hidden;` is that `none` takes the element out of the document flow and `visibility` just hides it. So by using `hidden`, the possibility that you get weird layout effects is reduced.

Comment: Better to take toggle()  <th class="hideHeader">    $('.hideHeader').toggle();

Answer (score 2):

You want to use

```
<th style="display: none;">
```

Alternatively a class:

```
.hide { display: none; }

<th class="hide">
```

You'll want to make sure this `class` or `style` is on both the `<th>` and the corresponding `<td>`

If you want to toggle visibility with jQuery you can apply a class to both the `<th>` and the `<td>` (e.g. "engcol") and then use `.toggle()` like so:

```
$('.engcol').toggle();
```